# Query a set with an regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, set

I have a set of strings and I want to ask it for all contained elements, that match a specific RegEx. For example:

```
set = set(['abcd', 'abdd', 'acdd'])
set.findAll('ab.d')
```

This should return:

```
['abcd', 'abdd']
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Give your variable a name other than `set`. Overriding the builtin can have weird behaviour, and it makes your code harder to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over all elements in the set, and filter on the regex:

```
>>> s = {'abcd', 'abdd', 'acdd'}
>>> r = [el for el in s if re.search('ab.d', el)]
>>> r
['abcd', 'abdd']
```

Comment: Why `s` is a dictionary without values?

Comment: @gabra You can have a look at [sets and read more here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Comment: @BhargavRao It would be better to link to the [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Comment: Should compile the regex beforehand to make the list comprehension more efficient: `pattern  = re.compile('ab.d')` and then use `pattern.search` inside.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.search` within a list comprehension :

```
>>> s=set(['abcd', 'abdd', 'acdd'])
>>> [i for i in s if re.search(r'ab.d',i)]
['abcd', 'abdd']
```

Comment: I think the OP used a toy example for the regex, and the real-world case is more complicated. Also your example fails for `'cab'`, which does not match `ab.`, but does get caught by `'ab' in i`.

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) as in

```
>>> s = {'abcd', 'abdd', 'acdd'}
>>> pat = re.compile('ab.d')
>>> map(lambda x:x.string,filter(None, map(pat.search,s)))
['abcd', 'abdd']
```

Note that `map` is microscopically faster than a list comprehension.

```
bhargav@bhargav:~$ python -m timeit "import re;s = {'abcd', 'abdd', 'acdd'};[el for el in s if re.search('ab.d', el)]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.59 usec per loop
bhargav@bhargav:~$ python -m timeit "import re;s = {'abcd', 'abdd', 'acdd'};pat = re.compile('ab.d'); map(lambda x:x.string,filter(None, map(pat.search,s)))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.21 usec per loop
```

As you can see, using `map` and `filter` makes it `0.38` microseconds faster.

However if you consider readability [orlp's list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29657728/4099593) is better. (In that case, this is an alternative way)

Comment: Updated answer for the asked proof for speed @GNU

Comment: @BhargavRao the list comprehension is actually significantly faster if you compile the regex.

Comment: @tzaman There you go! The *secretive* reason why I compiled it. If orlp, does the same, I'll gladly delete my answer. Ty